# Get Text of a ContextMenu.ItemsSource generated MenuItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I´ve got a Click-method of a MenuItem in a ContextMenu. In this method, I need the text of the item I´ve clicked.

Here´s the code:

```
private void menuItemKostenstellen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }
```

I already tried with e.Source but that didn´t work.

How can I get this?

Comment: are you subscribing directly to the event? please show the code how you react to the menu item click.

Comment: May be it's also interesting for you more general [event handler case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19178803/2154510)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following:

```
<ContextMenu Name="conKostenstelle" >
 <MenuItem Header="Kostenstellen" Name="menuItemKostenstellen">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_Click" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>

 </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>

 LinkedList<String> kliste = kosrep.GetKostenstellen();

menuItemKostenstellenunter.ItemsSource = kliste;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void menuItemKostenstellen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
            string title = mi.Header.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. With this code, I get the Header of my MenuItems. I need to get one level depper.

Comment: What do you mean one level deeper? can you show picture? also use the properties of `mi` to get anything that exists under it

Comment: Ok, heres the picture: [link](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/2760/rhuvrq4i_jpg.htm)[/link].
When I write `mi.Header.ToString()` I get "Kostenstellen" but I need "Reschinator", "Steuern" ...

Comment: You should handle click on sub menu item then.

Comment: `<ContextMenu   Name="conKostenstelle" >
                    <MenuItem Header="Kostenstellen" Name="menuItemKostenstellen" Click="menuItemKostenstellen_Click" />
                </ContextMenu>
 LinkedList<String> kliste = kosrep.GetKostenstellen();
            menuItemKostenstellenunter.ItemsSource = kliste;`

But thats not possible like you see above

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemContainerStyle Property for Click Event on all MenuItems

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_Click" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```